# Not able to upload with sound cloud console app

Tags: soundcloud

I have tried to upload a mp3 file using sound cloud console app

https://developers.soundcloud.com/console

parameters I am giving are

format: json
title : Title
asset_data: C:\Users\Admin\Music\songs\audio.mp3

using Post

I am getting error

HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that works:

```
C:\>"Share on SoundCloud.exe" /client_id:YOUR_CLIENT_ID /track[asset_data]:audio.mp3 /track[title]:"Test Sound" /oauth_token:YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Be aware that in your case, instead of `audio.mp3`, you should put `"C:/Users/Admin/Music/songs/audio.mp3"`.

Comment: thanks for your answer i have don't this using curl.exe c++ library